# Checking attributes of a function pointer?

Tags: c++11, function-pointers, generic-programming, pointer-to-member, c++14

Assume that I've got the following piece of code, in a generic context;

```
auto function = T::getFunctionPtr();
```

Is it possible to check whether 'function' is a global function versus a static class method, at compile time?

Comment: I don't think so, there is not much difference between static member function and non-member function. Why would you need this?

Comment: @zch: I agree, that there isn't a lot of difference, and I've been unable to find a way to query for the staticness, hence the question. Also I don't have a real life application, I'm just curious as to whether it can be decided using templates.

Comment: If I understood correctly, `T::getFunctionPtr()` returns a function pointer, i.e. something of a type like `void (*)(int, char)`. Then at this point the returned pointer can point to a global function or a static member function indifferently. The differences (scope, accessibility), which were visible from inside the definition of `T::getFunctionPtr()`, are no longer visible after you got a pointer. (Now that's not a real answer so I just make it a comment.)

Comment: @gx_: Assuming you change the above code, such that it states `T::some_function_name` instead of `T::getFunctionPtr()`, how would you figure if this function was static or not? I was thinking, that one could use SFINAE, based on the fact that doing `T::some_function_name`, where `some_function_name` is non-static function yields an error alike; `call to non-static member function without an object argument`, while it succeeds in the static case, however I can't seem to find a way to make use of SFINAE in this case.

Comment: @Skeen Weren't you asking to differentiate between a _global (non-member)_ function and a _static member_ function? `T::some_function_name` clearly can't be global (assuming `T` is a type). If now you're asking to differentiate between a _non-static member_ function and a _static member_ function, you should edit your question, but that would mean two different pointer types (e.g. `void (Foo::*)(int, char)` vs `void (*)(int, char)`).

Comment: @gx_: I guess my question rather boils down to, how can I check if a function is a global function or any kind of member function (static or not)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to check at compile time if 'function' is a global function or a static class method is to check the return type of 'T::getFunctionPtr()'. But global functions and static class methods have the same type, as shown here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

void GlobalFunc() {}

class A {
  public:
    static void StaticFunc() {}
};

int main() {
  cout << std::boolalpha;
  cout << (typeid(GlobalFunc) == typeid(A::StaticFunc)) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

outputs "true". http://ideone.com/oo70F9 .
So the answer is no, you can't do this at compile time.